# sjmisc::merge_imputations() averages across imputed datasets, which seems unjustified?

Tags: missing-data, imputation, r-mice

The [sjmisc package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjmisc/sjmisc.pdf) has a function `sjmisc::merge_imputations()`

> This function merges multiple imputed data frames from mice::mids()-objects into a single data frame by computing the mean or selecting the most likely imputed value.

I think this is what Stef van Buuren cautions against in [5.1.2 Not recommended workflow: Averaging the data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/workflow.html) ?

> the procedure ignores the between-imputation variability, and hence shares all the drawbacks of single imputation

Instead, they advocate for `mice::with()` and `mice::pool()`.

So when might one use `sjmisc::merge_imputations()` ?

Comment: This question may get better answers on Cross Validated, since it's really about the statistics and not the programming. If you want you can flag the question for migration.

Answer (score 1):

If:

1. The researcher either only cares about means, not about correlations or other more complicated relationships between variables. Or, is willing to assume that the imputation models were "true" models.
2. The researcher only cares about point estimates, and is less concerned about the uncertainty in those estimates (variance, standard errors, confidence intervals, hypothesis tests, coefficients of variation).
3. There is only a small amount of missing data.

Then averaging the imputed values can be a reasonable fix. Averaging the imputed values is basically a version of "stochastic regression imputation". Although note that as the number of imputations increases, averaging the imputed values converges to simple regression imputation. It's still *wrong*, but it may be a practical method. The sjmisc package documentation quotes Burns et al (2011). https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2010.10.011 From that article:

> There were practical benefits in providing DYNOPTA investigators an averaged imputation score as it precludes the necessity for investigators to run MICE for different projects using the MMSE, the need to obtain software capable of combining and analyzing multiple imputed datasets, and many investigators are unfamiliar with MI analysis techniques.

Compare also [van Buuren 1.3.5](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-simplesolutions.html#sec:sri)

If you have the ability to use proper pooling methods I would recommend using those instead.